# How to replace mutliple values in XML file using PowerShell

Tags: xml, powershell

In my example XML file, i need to replace the two Live DB Server variables with two new variables:

```
$newdb1 = "newproductiondb1"
$newdb2 = "newproductiondb2"
```

My current XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<databases>
 <database name="Live">
 <db1 server="productiondb1" dbname="Live1" />
 <db2 server="productiondb2" dbname="Live2" />
 </database>
 <database name="UAT">
 <db1 server="uatdb1" dbname="UAT1" />
 <db2 server="uatdb2" dbname="UAT2" />
 </database>
 <database name="QA">
 <db1 server="qadb1" dbname="QA1" /> 
 <db2 server="qadb2" dbname="QA2" />
</databases>
```

I cant find the syntax to replace the two variables ('db server' and 'db2 server') within the file just for the Live section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example how you can change this attributes:

```
$xml = [xml](Get-Content -Path C:\temp\test.xml)
$xml.SelectNodes("//database[@name='Live']") | foreach{
    $_.db1.server = "NewName1"
    $_.db2.server = "NewName2"
}
# Pretty Print and save File
$XmlWriterSettings = New-Object -TypeName System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings
$XmlWriterSettings.Indent = $true
$XmlWriterSettings.IndentChars = "`t"
$XmlWriterSettings.OmitXmlDeclaration = $true
$XmlWriter = [System.Xml.XmlWriter]::Create("C:\temp\test.xml", $XmlWriterSettings)
$xml.Save($XmlWriter)
$XmlWriter.Close()
```

Note: xPath is casesensitive